# Change existing element name using the attribute value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I got an XML file that's using very generic XML tag names but a rich attribute structure such as:
`<Field Name="CRSDESC1" FieldName="{@CRS_DESC}"><FormattedValue>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</FormattedValue></Field>`

I want to change the existing element name as shown above by using the "Name" attribute, to this: 
    `<CRSDESC1>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</CRSDESC1>`

Once we create the new element, we no longer need the element `<FormattedValue>` nor the duplicate `<Value>`

Here is a sample section of the XML:

`<CrystalReport> <ReportHeader><Details Level="1">
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Field Name="CRSDESC1" FieldName="{@CRS_DESC}"><FormattedValue>Heating and Air Contracting</FormattedValue><Value>Heating and Air Contracting</Value></Field>
<Field Name="CRSTITLE1" FieldName="{@CRS_TITLE}"><FormattedValue>Heating and Air Conditioning Contracting</FormattedValue><Value>Heating and Air Conditioning Contracting</Value></Field>
<Field Name="CRSDEPTS1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_DEPTS}"><FormattedValue>AIRC</FormattedValue><Value>AIRC</Value></Field>
<Field Name="DEPTSDESC1" FieldName="{Command.DEPTS_DESC}"><FormattedValue>Heating, A/C &amp; Refrigeration</FormattedValue><Value>Heating, A/C &amp; Refrigeration</Value></Field>
<Field Name="CRSNO1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_NO}"><FormattedValue>2260</FormattedValue><Value>2260</Value></Field>
<Field Name="CRSSTANDARDARTICULATIONNO1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_STANDARD_ARTICULATION_NO}"><FormattedValue></FormattedValue><Value></Value></Field>
<Field Name="CRSMINCRED1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_MIN_CRED}"><FormattedValue>3.00</FormattedValue><Value>3.00</Value></Field>
   </Section>
   </Details>
   <Details Level="1">
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Field Name="CRSDESC1" FieldName="{@CRS_DESC}"><FormattedValue>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</FormattedValue><Value>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</Value></Field>
<Field Name="CRSTITLE1" FieldName="{@CRS_TITLE}"><FormattedValue>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</FormattedValue><Value>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</Value></Field>
<Field Name="CRSDEPTS1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_DEPTS}"><FormattedValue>ANAT</FormattedValue><Value>ANAT</Value></Field>
<Field Name="DEPTSDESC1" FieldName="{Command.DEPTS_DESC}"><FormattedValue>Anatomy &amp; Physiology</FormattedValue><Value>Anatomy &amp; Physiology</Value></Field>
<Field Name="CRSNO1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_NO}"><FormattedValue>1500</FormattedValue><Value>1500</Value></Field>
<Field Name="CRSSTANDARDARTICULATIONNO1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_STANDARD_ARTICULATION_NO}"><FormattedValue>L1 904L</FormattedValue><Value>L1 904L</Value></Field>
<Field Name="CRSMINCRED1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_MIN_CRED}"><FormattedValue>4.00</FormattedValue><Value>4.00</Value></Field>
</Section>
</Details> <ReportHeader><CrystalReport>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work...

**XML Input** (corrected to be well-formed)

```
<CrystalReport>
    <ReportHeader>
        <Details Level="1">
            <Section SectionNumber="0">
                <Field Name="CRSDESC1" FieldName="{@CRS_DESC}">
                    <FormattedValue>Heating and Air Contracting</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>Heating and Air Contracting</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="CRSTITLE1" FieldName="{@CRS_TITLE}">
                    <FormattedValue>Heating and Air Conditioning Contracting</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>Heating and Air Conditioning Contracting</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="CRSDEPTS1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_DEPTS}">
                    <FormattedValue>AIRC</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>AIRC</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="DEPTSDESC1" FieldName="{Command.DEPTS_DESC}">
                    <FormattedValue>Heating, A/C &amp; Refrigeration</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>Heating, A/C &amp; Refrigeration</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="CRSNO1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_NO}">
                    <FormattedValue>2260</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>2260</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="CRSSTANDARDARTICULATIONNO1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_STANDARD_ARTICULATION_NO}">
                    <FormattedValue/>
                    <Value/>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="CRSMINCRED1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_MIN_CRED}">
                    <FormattedValue>3.00</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>3.00</Value>
                </Field>
            </Section>
        </Details>
        <Details Level="1">
            <Section SectionNumber="0">
                <Field Name="CRSDESC1" FieldName="{@CRS_DESC}">
                    <FormattedValue>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="CRSTITLE1" FieldName="{@CRS_TITLE}">
                    <FormattedValue>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="CRSDEPTS1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_DEPTS}">
                    <FormattedValue>ANAT</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>ANAT</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="DEPTSDESC1" FieldName="{Command.DEPTS_DESC}">
                    <FormattedValue>Anatomy &amp; Physiology</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>Anatomy &amp; Physiology</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="CRSNO1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_NO}">
                    <FormattedValue>1500</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>1500</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="CRSSTANDARDARTICULATIONNO1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_STANDARD_ARTICULATION_NO}">
                    <FormattedValue>L1 904L</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>L1 904L</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="CRSMINCRED1" FieldName="{Command.CRS_MIN_CRED}">
                    <FormattedValue>4.00</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>4.00</Value>
                </Field>
            </Section>
        </Details>
    </ReportHeader>
</CrystalReport>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Field[@Name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="FormattedValue"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<CrystalReport>
   <ReportHeader>
      <Details Level="1">
         <Section SectionNumber="0">
            <CRSDESC1>Heating and Air Contracting</CRSDESC1>
            <CRSTITLE1>Heating and Air Conditioning Contracting</CRSTITLE1>
            <CRSDEPTS1>AIRC</CRSDEPTS1>
            <DEPTSDESC1>Heating, A/C &amp; Refrigeration</DEPTSDESC1>
            <CRSNO1>2260</CRSNO1>
            <CRSSTANDARDARTICULATIONNO1/>
            <CRSMINCRED1>3.00</CRSMINCRED1>
         </Section>
      </Details>
      <Details Level="1">
         <Section SectionNumber="0">
            <CRSDESC1>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</CRSDESC1>
            <CRSTITLE1>Survey of Human Anatomy and Physiology</CRSTITLE1>
            <CRSDEPTS1>ANAT</CRSDEPTS1>
            <DEPTSDESC1>Anatomy &amp; Physiology</DEPTSDESC1>
            <CRSNO1>1500</CRSNO1>
            <CRSSTANDARDARTICULATIONNO1>L1 904L</CRSSTANDARDARTICULATIONNO1>
            <CRSMINCRED1>4.00</CRSMINCRED1>
         </Section>
      </Details>
   </ReportHeader>
</CrystalReport>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Can you give me any suggestions why it wouldn't work for me? I'm still seeing all the original tag names and structure.

Comment: I ran your XSLT against the sample data you revised and it worked fine. What was the problem you fixed in the data to make it well-formed? I don't see an issue in the data off-hand

Comment: OK, I see that you moved the end of </ReportHeader> to the end of the XML. That's not how it appears in the actual XML. There is a <ReportHeader> and a <ReportFooter> in the actual XML. When I deleted the DTD in my actual XML file your XSL functioned properly. Thanks

Comment: @JimMaivald - What I did was change the last 2 tags (`<ReportHeader><CrystalReport>`) to `</ReportHeader></CrystalReport>`. Glad you got it figured out.